# Title Case All Question Titles Everywhere!

Tags: script, style, stylish

Because some like it like that:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document regexp("*.stackexchange.com|superuser.com|askubuntu.com|serverfault.com|mathoverflow.com|stackapps.com|stackoverflow.com")
{
  #question-header, 
 .summary h3 a,
  #hot-network-questions li ,
  div.spacer a
  {text-transform: capitalize !important;}
}
```

Comment: i prefer lower case myself - how would you do this?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry just type [`lowercase`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp) instead :p

Comment: where? after capitalize, or before?

Comment: Instead! Replace the word "capitalize" with "lowercase".