# Why is comment_count=1 (incorrectly) when this particular filter is used?

Tags: bug, questions, api-v2.2, comments

We're seeing that, when a particular filter we've created is used, the API will return `"comment_count": 1` for questions with no comments.

For a search for questions with no answers, ordered by descending creation date, with our filter applied: [Many questions with no comments are returned with `"comment_count": 1`.](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!E-NSrt401eBQ_xSbAwzGK5%29eaAlq.xOHAf0SZE&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

---

[Here's the response for question ID 28269098, with `comment_count` added to the default filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=28269098&filter=!9YdnSHlXz&site=stackoverflow&run=true). It **correctly** returned `"comment_count": 0` (back when the question didn't have any comments):

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      ...
      "comment_count": 0,
      ...
      "question_id": 28269098,
      "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269098/resize-uibuttons-iphone-5-to-iphone-6-ratio",
      "title": "Resize UIButtons iPhone 5 to iPhone 6 ratio"
    }
```

But [here's the response for question ID 28269098, with our problem filter applied](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=28269098&filter=!E-NSrt401eBQ_xSbAwzGK5%29eaAlq.xOHAf0SZE&site=stackoverflow&run=true), which **incorrectly** returns `"comment_count": 1` for the same question:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      ...
      "comment_count": 1,
      ...
      "question_id": 28269098,
      "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269098/resize-uibuttons-iphone-5-to-iphone-6-ratio",
      "title": "Resize UIButtons iPhone 5 to iPhone 6 ratio"
    }
```

**(Editor's note. Now that that question has comments (currently 3), the OP's query returns the correct number. But I have confirmed this bug on posts with no comments.)**

Why is `comment_count` returning an invalid value, for comment-less posts, when we use our filter?

Comment: I can confirm that this behaviour still exists in the current API version. I've noticed the wrong comment_count value of 1 as well on quite a lot of questions without comments.

Comment: Bug still exists even now :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirmed the bug on [a post that accrues comments much slower than a typical Stack Overflow question does](https://stackapps.com/q/6137/7653).

Currently, [the OP's filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=6137&filter=!E-NSrt401eBQ_xSbAwzGK5%29eaAlq.xOHAf0SZE&site=stackapps&run=true) returns `"comment_count": 1` on that post. There are no comments.

I believe this is a side-effect/bug/quirk with how the API appears to be counting the comments.  ¿Perhaps it is counting `Id`s in the comment table and not properly coalescing a null (or properly forming the join) when comments are turned off by the filter?

Anyway, altering the OP's filter by:

- selecting `comment.comment_id`
- and selecting `question.comments`

[As seen in **this query**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=6137&filter=!-xzz8_7XD4SyVIP_O%28%29Xz3hyFmYX.tzE96njeLJgz&site=stackapps&run=true), works-around the problem.  It currently returns `"comment_count": 0` (Correct) for [that question](https://stackapps.com/q/6137/7653).