# Field "comment_count" is not always returned by API

Tags: bug, questions, api-v2.2, comments, filter

I am making a request with a custom filter that includes the `"comment_count"` field of the [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) type. My custom filter is `!RtdMEtslKF6Z()NqpDUFZ58R6twu-.4V48gn0furqA*7_BL1`.

However, when I'm querying [the question having an ID of 14585943](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14585943/331508), which has no comments (at this date), [the field `"comment_count` isn't returned by the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/14585943?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!RtdMEtslKF6Z()NqpDUFZ58R6twu-.4V48gn0furqA*7_BL1).

[image]

It should be returned, even if there are no comments, because the documentation doesn't specify that this field "may be absent".

I tested this [with the even simpler filter `!.UE46pK5nV.kgRss`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/14585943?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE46pK5nV.kgRss), which includes no fields, except `.items`, `question.comment_count` and `question.title`. The comment count still isn't returned (when the title is correctly returned).

A couple of notes that I gathered:

- `"comment_count"` [is correctly returned](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/38951098?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!.UE46pK5nV.kgRss) (with the correct count) by both filters above if there are comments on the question.
- `"comment_count"` [is always correctly returned](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/14585943?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9YdnSHlY() if the filter used consists of the default filter, added with `question.comment_count`. In this request, the result has `"comment_count":0` for questions without comments.

As such, it appears that the problem only happens when there are no comments and specific fields aren't included in the filter. (I am not sure which specific fields -- I tried to isolate to a single field but wasn't successful).

Comment: I can confirm this problem, had this with my filter too on some occasions.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be closely related to the bug: [*Why is comment_count=1 (incorrectly) when this particular filter is used?*](https://stackapps.com/questions/6145/why-is-comment-count-1-incorrectly-when-this-particular-filter-is-used).

The workaround from there -- altering the filter by:

- selecting `comment.comment_id`
- and selecting `question.comments`

[appears to work in this case too](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=14585943&filter=!C(o*Vgsv-sR*NeGm.&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

(Although, in at least one instance, it seemed to need `question_id` as well.  But this could have been a caching issue, maybe.)

Comment: Ok this seems to work, thanks. But how come the default filter + comment_count also works? `question.comments` isn't included there. (Huh, I just tried and it worked without it now... I'll blame caching)

Comment: Something very weird is going on, start from the filter in this answer, remove `question.comments`, click Run, `comment_count` is still returned. Remove `comment.comment_id`, click Run, `comment_count` is not returned anymore. Re-add `comment.comment_id`, click Run, `comment_count` is still not returned =/

Comment: See the other bug.  Part of the reason to include both properties is so you don't stumble into *that* bug when you think you've got *this* bug worked around.  As for the rest, it's frustrating.  Queries are cached and some filters affect that and some don't, and some additional flakiness seems to be occurring too.

Comment: Maybe I'll take the simpler route: if the field isn't there, it means the comment count is 0 :). Hopefully a dev will look at this, thanks again!